# Draw/plot a heart graph

Tags: code-golf, math, graphical-output

Your challenge is to draw/plot one of the hearts below. The size must be at least 50x50 pixels (vector graphics is OK). You may choose which of the hearts you want to draw/plot. Axes, grid lines etc. are accepted. There must be **at least** 100 distinct coordinates/points on the graph. The heart can be filled with color if you want to.

[image]

The equations are either:

[image]

**or**

[image]

[image]

`t` is in the range `[-1, 1]`.

**or**

[image]

**or**

[image]

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code (in each language) in bytes wins. Please provide the output (or link to an online interpreter).

Answer (score 68):

## TI-80 BASIC, <s>45</s> <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
LBL 1
RAND4-2->X
RAND4-2
IF (X²+ANS²-1)³<X²ANS³
PT-ON(X,ANS
GOTO 1
```

[image]

This took a while, and my battery is low so I didn't want to keep going.

I tried to use the second equation, but <s>couldn't get it to work</s> it actually turned out to be longer, so I just adapted the other answer I had.

EDIT: I just noticed the 50x50 pixel requirement, unfortunately the screen is only 47 pixels high so this isn't possible.

Comment: creative indeed!

Comment: It's been a while, but can you replace `IF (X²+ANS²-1)³-X²ANS³<0` with `IF (X²+ANS²-1)³<X²ANS³`?

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I didn't think of that! thanks

Answer (score 47):

### Perl, 86 bytes

```
$y=1-$_/25,say+map$y**3*($_*=$_/1e3)-($_+$y**2-1)**3>0?$|--?v60:3:$",-40..40for-6..50
```

Run with `perl -E`.

Plots a filled ASCII heart, using the first equation. Note that the x-axis is
stretched by a factor of ~1.265: this is to counteract the fact that terminal
fonts are usually much bigger vertically than horizontally.

Output:

```
                3<3<3<3<3<3<3<                   3<3<3<3<3<3<3<                 
              3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<           3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<               
            3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<       3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<             
          3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<   3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<           
         3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3< 3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<          
        3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3 <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<         
       3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3        
      <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<       
      3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3       
     <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<      
     3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3      
    <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<     
    3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3     
    <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<     
    3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3     
    <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<     
   3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3    
   <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<    
    3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3     
    <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<     
    3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3     
    <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<     
    3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3     
     <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<      
     3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3      
     <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<      
      3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3       
      <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<       
       3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3        
       <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<        
        3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3         
         <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<          
         3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3          
          <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<           
           3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3            
            <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<             
             3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3              
              <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<               
               3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3                
                <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<                 
                 3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3                  
                  <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<                   
                   3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3                    
                     <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<                      
                      3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3                       
                       <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<                        
                         3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3                          
                           <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<                            
                            3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3                             
                              <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<                               
                                3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3                                 
                                  <3<3<3<3<3<                                   
                                    3<3<3<3                                     
                                     <3<3<                                      
                                       3
```

Explanation (since OP asked for it):

```
condition := $y**3*($_*=$_/1e3)-($_+$y**2-1)**3>0
```

This is simply the first equation, slightly rearranged to make it shorter.
$y directly represents the y in the formula. $_ is initially proportional to x,
but is multiply-assigned with itself (`$_*=$_/1e3`), making it proportional to x².
Since x² is used twice in the formula, this saves a few bytes.

`1e3` means 1000, and was picked because it’s short and the result looks good. `**`
is Perl’s power operator. I use `>0` rather than `==0` because I want a filled heart.

```
flip_flop := $|--?v60:3
```

v60 is an abuse of the archaic version-string syntax to denote the character with
ASCII code 60: '<'.

$| is a magical variable that can only ever be 0 or 1. Decrementing when it’s
already 0 sets it to 1. Decrementing when it’s 1 naturally sets it to 0. Thus,
$|-- is often used as a flip-flop: each time it’s evaluated, it alternates
between true and false.

As a whole, this expression returns alternatively '<' and 3.

```
inner_loop := <condition> ? <flip_flop> :$"
```

Nested ternaries. If condition is false (→ we’re outside the heart), evaluates to $",
which is a magical variable that defaults to " " (a single space). If condition is true
(→ we’re inside the heart), it evaluates flip_flop.

```
outer_loop := say+map <inner_loop> ,-40..40
```

Evaluates inner_loop repeatedly, with $_ (Perl’s “default” variable) going from -40 to 40, in increments of 1.
It collects the results of those evaluation in a temporary list, then prints them all, concatenated, ending with a new line.

```
$y=1-$_/25, <outer_loop> for-6..50
```

This runs outer_loop repeatedly, with $y going from 1.24 (1 - (-6 / 25)) to -1 (1 - 50 / 25), in decrements of 0.04.

Note that y is divided by 25, while x² is divided by 1000, which is the same as dividing x by sqrt(1000). The ~1.265 factor I mentioned is sqrt(1000) / 25.

Comment: Huh, I guess it doesn't violate any rules... My favorite so far :) I'd love an explanation though :)

Comment: I'm confused about something. Why use ?v60 over, say, "<"?

Comment: Same length, but easier to type.

Comment: A heart made from hearts.

Answer (score 34):

## <strike>Mathematica</strike> WolframAlpha, <strike>17</strike> <strike>15</strike> <strike>13</strike> 11 bytes

Shaved off 2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender (1st heart curve -> heart curve 1)

Shaved off another 2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender (heart curve 1 -> heartcurve1)

This is probably cheating (the obvious solution), but here goes.

```
heartcurve1
```

[Try it here!](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=heartcurve1)

<strike>I'm sure there's a way to shorten 1st, heart or curve such that Wolfram still accepts it.</strike>  Well it's free of spaces now, maybe some sort of abbreviation for heart?

Do I get bonus points for plotting 2 of them?

```
heartcurves
```

[Try that here!](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=heartcurves)

Comment: `heart curve 1`

Comment: Actually, `heartcurve1` works.

Comment: @MartinEnder What in the world

Comment: first one of heartcurves looks more like a butt though

Comment: @MikhailV 0th heartcurve (cardoid) looks like a butt.

Comment: it's a buttoid  :-)

Answer (score 29):

### Mathematica, 52 bytes

```
RegionPlot[(x^2+y^2-1)^3-x^2y^3<0,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]
```

[image]

We could save one more byte with `ContourPlot` but then the background gets a bit trippy:

```
ContourPlot[(x^2+y^2-1)^3-x^2y^3,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]
```

[image]

For one *additional* byte we could use the fourth formula and `PolarPlot` instead:

```
PolarPlot[(x=Sin@t)Abs@Cos@t^.5/(x+7/5)-2x+2,{t,0,7}]
```

[image]

Comment: "A bit trippy" is a bit of an understatement...

Answer (score 26):

## Casio fx-7700GH, 21 bytes

```
sin θ √ Abs cos θ ÷ ( sin θ + 7 ÷ 5 ) - 2 sin θ + 2
```

Unnamed graph function to be entered into one of the polar coordinate graphing function slots, then does what it says on the tin.

The graphing range must be manually set (unless it happens to fit to the current set range), I set it to `Xmin=-2.75, Xmax=2.75, Ymin=-4, Ymax=1`.

Should work on other Casio Power Graphic Series calculators too, and quite possibly later Casio graphic calculators.

[image: A heart drawn by a Casio fx-7700GH calculator]
(yep <s>I'm</s> pretty old and dusty)

Answer (score 18):

## MATLAB / Octave, 31 bytes

```
ezplot('(x^2+y^2-1)^3-x^2*y^3')
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

### [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), <strike>20 16</strike> 15 bytes

V 2:

```
xx).3y=xx+yy-1
```

( = `xx)^.3y=xx+yy-1`)

V 1:

```
xx+yy-1)3=xxy3
```

V 0:

```
(x2+y2-1)3=x2y3
```

Comment: you could use `xx` instead of `x^2`

Comment: Your byte count is wrong, you have an extra newline.

Comment: @Riker, I don't see how it's wrong. Where is there a newline?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/4eTyt V2 is 14 bytes

Comment: @Riker, ah you forgot the `^`. It's really `xx)^.3=xx+yy-1`

Comment: @Dopapp then your answer is wrong.....

Comment: @Riker, no. As you can see the `.3` is a superscript, hence an exponent...

Comment: @Dopapp wait, so is that 2 bytes? If so, can you just change it to ^3? It's the same amount of bytes, and clarifies for people reading the answer.

Comment: @Riker better now?

Answer (score 9):

## SmileBASIC, <s>85</s> 81 bytes

```
X=RNDF()*4-2Y=RNDF()*4-2GPSET X*50+99,Y*50+99,-(-X*X*Y*Y*Y>POW(X*X+Y*Y-1,3))EXEC.
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## MATL, 36 bytes

```
1e4t:w/EqXJX,JY,J|Yl**JX,X^J|.3^*&XG
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=1e4t%3Aw%2FEqXJX%2CJY%2CJ%7CYl%2a%2aJX%2CX%5EJ%7C.3%5E%2a%26XG&inputs=&version=19.7.4)

[image]

Comment: Tfw MATL solution is longer than MATLAB :)

Answer (score 7):

## Python, <s>119</s> 116 bytes

```python
from turtle import*
from math import*
t=1
while-t<1:a=abs(t);c=cos(t);goto(sin(t)*c*log(a)*99,c**.5*a**.3*99);t-=.01
```

[**Try it online**](https://trinket.io/python/cdbc87c4f3)

[image: x=sin(t)*cos(t)*log(abs(t))]

[image: y=cos(t)**.5*abs(t)**.3]

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
*3×
²+’*3<çị⁾* 
25µNr÷21µ²ç@þUY
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ATEAzv//KjPDlwrCsivigJkqMzzDp@G7i@KBviogCjI1wrVOcsO3MjHCtcKyw6dAw75VWf//)**

or **[35 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ATcAyP//KjPDlwrCsivigJkqMzzDp8OXOTgyOeG7jMK74oG2CjI1wrVOcsO3MjHCtcKyw6dAw75VWf//)** with a `♥`, rather than `*` fill: change middle line to `²+’*3<ç×9829Ọ»⁶`.

```
          ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥           ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥          
        ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥       ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥        
      ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥   ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥      
     ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥ ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥     
     ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥ ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥     
    ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥    
   ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥   
   ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥   
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥  
   ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥   
   ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥   
   ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥   
    ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥    
    ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥    
     ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥     
     ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥     
      ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥      
      ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥      
       ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥       
        ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥        
        ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥        
         ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥         
          ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥          
           ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥           
            ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥            
             ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥             
              ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥              
               ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥               
                 ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥                 
                  ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥                  
                   ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥                   
                     ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥                     
                      ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥                      
                        ♥♥♥                        
                         ♥
```

#### How?

Implements: [image: equation] over a 51 by 51 line feed separated grid of characters.

```
*3× - Link 1: y, xSquared
*3  - cube y
  × - multiply the result by xSquared

²+’*3<çị⁾*  - Link 2: y, xSquared
²           - square y
 +          - add xSquared to the result
  ’         - subtract one
   *3       - cube the result
     <      - less than? (1 if True, 0 if False)
      ç     -     the result of the last link (1) as a dyad: f(y, xSquared)
       ị    - index into (1-based):
        ⁾*  - the string "* " (there is a trailing space on this line)

       ×9829Ọ»⁶ - alternative ending of link 2
       ×9829    - multiply (vectorises) by 9829
            Ọ   - cast to character (vectorises) (9829 is the ♥, 0 is the null-byte)
             »  - maximum (vectorises) of that and:
              ⁶ -     space character (ordinal of space is 32, greater than the null-byte, less than ♥)

25µNr÷21µ²ç@þUY - Main link: no arguments
25              - 25
  µ             - monadic chain separation call that i
   N            - negate i
    r           - inclusive range(negated i, i) -> [-25, -24, ..., 24, 25]
     ÷21        - divide by 21 (vectorises) -> [-1.1904761904761905, -1.1428571428571428, ..., 1.1428571428571428, 1.1904761904761905]
        µ       - monadic chain separation call that r
         ²      - square r (vectorises) (make the xSquared values, left to right)
             U  - upend r (make the y values, top to bottom)
            þ   - outer product using:
          ç@    -     last link (2) as a dyad with reversed arguments: f(y, xSquared)
              Y - join with line feeds
                - implicit print
```

Answer (score 6):

### SageMath, 66 bytes

```py
polar_plot(sin(x)*abs(cos(x))^.5/(sin(x)+7/5)-2*sin(x)+2,(0,2*pi))
```

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwryM9JLIovyMkv0SjOzNOo0NRKTCrWSM4vBjI14_RM9aHC2ub6ppq6RlpQnpGOhoGOkVZBpqYmANUwE4E=&lang=sage)

Unfortunately, the long names of `implicit_plot` and `parametric_plot` (plus the need to define a variable other than the implicitly-defined `x` for the former) make the first three options much too long to be considered.

Thanks to busukxuan and Andrea Lazzarotto for a byte

Comment: Does `^.5` work in place of `**.5`?

Comment: @busukxuan Nope. Sage is built on Python, and `^` is XOR.

Comment: But sage substitutes `^` with `**`. I was wondering if it was because it couldn't substitute correctly if followed by a `.`

Comment: @busukxuan Sage uses Python's power notation (`**`). If you tried to use `^`, you'd end up with a warning and an incorrect result.

Comment: I took a [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4qGZ9_S-rqcV0VYUkpVUFhMUDg). I don't get it, could it be version differences?

Comment: @busukxuan Possibly. The online sagecell I used for the permalink is running an older version of Sage, and I don't really have a way to run a newer version right now outside of SageMathCloud.

Comment: @Mego Sage treats `^` as an exponentiation. Always did that and it works in the Sage Cell link you posted as an example. :) [Check it out here](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwryM9JLIovyMkv0SjOzNOo0NRKTCrWSM4vBjI14_RM9aHC2ub6ppq6RlpQnpGOhoGOkVZBpqYmANUwE4E=&lang=sage).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Then apparently my memory is faulty. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## C, <s>137</s> 133 bytes

```
p;float x,y,f;v(){for(p=4e3;p;x=(float)(p%99-50)/35,y=(float)(p/40-45)/40,f=x*x+y*y-1)putchar(p--%99?f*f*f-x*x*y*y*y<1e-3?35:32:10);}
```

http://codepad.org/zqqYUui8

Thanks @AlbertRenshaw, I also changed the 100s to 99s for 2 more bytes

Comment: +1; I like the use of `v` for the function, good flair. You can shave two bytes by replacing `4000` with `4e3` and replacing `0.001` with `1e-3`

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>151</s> 147 bytes

```js
document.write`<canvas id=c>`;for(i=0;x=2-i/24,i<97;i++)for(j=0;y=2-j/24,z=x*x+y*y-1,j<97;j++)z*z*z-x*x*y*y*y<0&&c.getContext`2d`.fillRect(i,j,1,1)
```

Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to @user2428118. ES7 version for 143 bytes:

```js
document.write`<canvas id=c>`;for(i=0;i<97;i++)for(x=2-i/24,j=0;j<97;j++)x*x*(y=2-j/24)**3-(x*x+y*y-1)**3>0&&c.getContext`2d`.fillRect(i,j,1,1)
```

Comment: how about `y**3` instead of `y*y*y` ?

Comment: @svarog Thus my note "Would be slightly shorter in ES7"...

Comment: well, it works on chromium 55, so why not add an es7 version ?

Comment: @svarog Because I don't have chromium 55 handy...

Comment: You could always use Babel...

Comment: You could probably save some bytes by using  template strings: ````document.write`<canvas id=c>`;```` and ````c.getContext`2d` ```` seem possible.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot It complained about undeclared variables when I tried.

Comment: @svarog Finally got around to updating to Firefox 52... only seems to save 4 bytes though.

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, 80 bytes

Show Ruby some love.

```
-2.step(2,0.2){|y|-2.step(2,0.1){|x|$><<'. O'[(y*y-1+x*=x)**3+x*y**3<=>0]};puts}
```

#### Output:

```
         OOOOO     OOOOO             
      .OOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOO.          
     OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO         
     OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO         
     OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO         
      OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO          
      .OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.          
        OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO            
         OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO             
           OOOOOOOOOOO               
              OOOOO                  
                .
```

with some empty lines above and below

Answer (score 4):

## BBC BASIC, 80

Will finish golfing tomorrow.

Download interpreter at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/bbcwin.html

```
ORIGIN99,99F.u=-56TO56x=u/50b=x^2^.33/2r=(b^2-x^2+1)^.5*50L.u,b*50-r,u,r+b*50N.
```

Draws a filled heart using the first equation, which we rearrange and take the cube root of (there are 3 cube roots of a real number, one real and 2 complex but we only interested in the real root here.) We then rearrange again to get a quadratic in `y`

```
x^2+y^2-1=(x^0.66)y

y^2-(x^0.66)y+x^2-1=0
```

Using the standard quadratic formula for expressions of the type `ay^2+by+c=0`, and taking advantage of the fact that `a`=1 we get

```
y = -b/2 +/- sqrt((b/2)^2-c)

y = -b/2 +/- sqrt((b/2)^2-x^2+1)
```

where `-b/2 = (x^0.66)/2` (represented by `b` in the program.)

We simply scan through the values of `x` from left to right, drawing a vertical line between each pair of valid values for `y` to build up a solid shape.

```
ORIGIN99,99F.u=-56TO56x=u/50b=x^2^.33/2r=(b^2-x^2+1)^.5*50L.u,b*50-r,u,r+b*50N.
```

**ungolfed**

```
ORIGIN99,99
FORu=-56TO56
  x=u/50
  b=x^2^.33/2
  r=(b^2-x^2+1)^.5*50
  LINEu,b*50+r,u,b*50-r
NEXT
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-84 Basic, <s>40</s> 38 bytes

Similar to @12Me21's answer & output, but for the TI-83/84 series instead.

```
While 1:2rand-1→A:2rand-1:If (A²+Ans²-1)³>A²Ans³:Pt-On(A,Ans:End
```

Comment: Is using Ans actually smaller here? I thought Ans was 2 bytes.

Comment: @12Me21 No, it's the same size, and faster too. (For TI-83/84 at least, I don't know about TI-80).

Answer (score 2):

### Processing.js: <s>123</s> 119 bytes

ungolfed:

```
t = 0; 

void setup() {
    size(99, 300); 
} 

void draw() {
    point(59+99*sin(t)*cos(t)*log(t),350-400*sqrt(cos(t))*pow(t,0.3));
    t+=0.01;
}
```

---

golfed:

```
t=0;void setup(){size(99,300);}void draw(){point(59+99*sin(t)*cos(t)*log(t),350-400*sqrt(cos(t))*pow(t,0.3));t+=0.01;}
```

this one is quite cheaty as it plots #2 from 0 to infinity instead of from -1 to 1 as shown in the picture to save on the two abs(t). But it's technically correct as there are more than 100 points.

---

130 bytes "correctier" one

```
t=-1;void setup(){size(99,300);}void draw(){point(59+99*sin(t)*cos(t)*log(abs(t)),350-400*sqrt(cos(t))*pow(abs(t),0.3));t+=0.01;}
```

---

[try it online](http://sketchpad.cc/sp/pad/view/aPbRMgtCTz/latest)

note : there's probably a way to get 100 points on the default 100x100 canvas and shave the setup off.

Comment: None of your snippets do anything for me on my local version of Processing (except for the second one which just draws 1 point)

Comment: have you tried on sketchpad? ("try it online") you need to click "render sketch"

Comment: But I think that would be called "Processing.JS" instead. For the snippet to work for me, you have to use `float` instead of `int`

Comment: oops, forgot the .js, and thanks to that I saved 4 bytes by removing the useless int.

Answer (score 1):

## BBC BASIC (BBC Micro) (126 bytes)

This is a variation of [Level River Street's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15599/level-river-st) [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110000), but for the original BBC Micro's iteration of BBC BASIC.

You can copy and paste either of the following into JSBeeb's new paste functionality at https://bbc.godbolt.org/ (A JavaScript powered BBC Micro emulator), once it has pasted, press Enter inside the 'screen' to show a new prompt, then type RUN, then press Enter to run either version.

golfed. (126 bytes)

```
1MO.1:V.29,64;64;:MOVE-57,20:GC.0,1:F.U=-56TO56:X=U/50:IFX<>0TH.B=X^2^.33/2
2R=(B^2-X^2+1)^.5*50:DRAWU,B*50+R:DRAW U,B*50-R:N.
```

ungolfed. (176 bytes)

```
1 MODE 1
2 VDU 29,64;64;
3 MOVE -57,20
4 GCOL 0,1
5 FOR U = -56 TO 56
6 X = U/50
7 IF X <> 0 THEN B = X^2^.33/2
8 R = (B^2-X^2+1)^.5*50
9 DRAW U,B*50+R
10 DRAW U,B*50-R
11 NEXT
```

Line 7 requires a check for X, to prevent a "Log range" error when X becomes 0 half way through the loop. Other than this, it's pretty much the same. It's a lot slower to draw on a real machine, which JSBeeb emulates pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets (Conditional Formatting), 73

Set conditional formatting on range A1:CV100:

```
=(2500/9-(Column()-25)^2-(ROW()-25)^2)^3>(Column()-25)^2*(ROW()-25)^3/.06
```

You'll have to adjust your columns/rows so that 100x100 cells fit on your screen. (10 pixels is a good value.) Colors the cells in the cardioid.