# Primitive roots density of number

Tags: math, number-theory, fastest-code

### Definition:

> A number **m** is called a primitive root of a prime **p** the condition that  the smallest integer **k** for which **p** dividies **m**<sup>**k**</sup>**-1** is **p-1**

### Your task

Given a tuple **(a,b)** of positive integers, return the fraction:

(number of primes **p** equal to or less than **a** which has **b** as a primitive root) divided by (number of primes equal to or less than **a**)

### Test Cases

Assuming [Artin's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) to be true, giving **(A very big number, 2)** should return a value around **.3739558136...**

**The challenge is for the fastest code, not necessarily the shortest one.**

### Timing

My crappy code takes 10 seconds for a million on my PC (intel i3 6th Gen, 8GB RAM, others I forgot), so your code should naturally beat that speed.

This is my first challenge. Feeback is appreciated. :)

Comment: Darn why there's no latex in CG SE :/

Comment: Type it [here](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), and post it as images. That's what I did in [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/109917/31516).

Comment: Can you add some test cases, please?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/fastest-code/info

Comment: You should specify how the code will be tested, by whom, and on what platform. Something like: _"The program must be able to handle 1 million in less than 1 minute on my computer: 
Specs: 4 CPUs, i5-4300U CPU @ 1.9 GHz, 7.5G of RAM. The program that finishes for 1 million the fastest wins."_ You need some way to determine the winner.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes, I should, but still I didn't because my desktop is sent away to be repaired, and now I'm working on the cheapest laptop of 2014, that too made by the stupidest company you can think of. I will update once I get my desktop back (after ~7 days, I think)

Comment: Why do you have a laptop made by Volkswagen???

Comment: "This is my first _golf_ challenge" I see no golfing required here, as it's [tag:fastest-code]

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/)

Around 0.6 sec for 1,000,000.

```c
int modpow(long b,int e,long n){
	long r=1;
	while(e){
		if(e&1) r=r*b%n;
		b=b*b%n;
		e>>=1;
	}
	return r;
}
float f(int a,int b){
	int ln=1;
	for(int p=2;p<=a;p*=ln,ln++);
	int* primes = malloc((a+1)*(sizeof(int)));
	int** factors = malloc((a+1)*sizeof(int*));
	primes[0] = 0;
	primes[1] = 0;
	for(int i=2;i<=a;i++){
		primes[i] = 1;
		factors[i] = malloc(ln*sizeof(int));
	}
	factors[1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
	factors[1][1] = 0;
	for(int p=2;p*p<=a;p++){
		if(primes[p]){
			for(int j=p*2;j<=a;j+=p){
				primes[j] = 0;
				factors[j][0]++;
				factors[j][factors[j][0]] = p;
			}
		}
	}
	int count1 = 0;
	int count2 = 0;
	for(int p=2;p<=a;p++){
		if(!primes[p]) continue;
		count2++;
		int n=p-1;
		int m=p-1;
		int prim=1;
		for(int j=1;j<=factors[n][0];j++){
			int q=factors[n][j];
			if(modpow(b,n/q,p)==1){
				prim=0;
				break;
			}
			while(m%q==0){
				m/=q;
			}
		}
		if(m>1){
			if(modpow(b,n/m,p)==1){
				prim=0;
			}
		}
		count1 += prim;
	}
	return (float)count1/count2;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPbjpswEH2Gr2C3SmUM28R5ZZ0fafMAxOyamrFDiFbaKt@eenwJZNNGQrJnzpw5c5xpX97a9vpNQqvOB5G9nqaDks2P9116F5Pahq4SpmzQB6M/iNLwljUlRkTpLpD/SRN3Gjmr0uTjXSpBBEYT2RHxneU2M9JmBTabNLyJR7HbuYpLmoxiOo@QjVV6STul6ynrCPaoXacGyfCgwBV0enRZw7eVeeV1ZShXUCooirxySJqZUQ7ilPFsqJXSLSF1wXJKTvJTaMed5xFLs65uJz0@oGcwdWDP@XOzt8DNfGfxHnVJq0uiLmkFoQ8BKBGIAyShoY@EngroUp03JgLZAvgFNUMelTiHqPcoaLFvEuSYvQvcwD03dFv1CO4Lbnwyau8jdTKr7/fWi6J4CN7lsc44iB0Hv4t/y1afYWKB9BbY/muAL/KfZv22CCYJZ4ENPIHXg7XAzQuLl2F5QQLuH@I2O8PJo3JA5dYF39PVHJfJfu8msmLCXjQlrI@lyTlnC994MKwZRf375kFYkWF15HwT0MOaH5cmOepd4LpvM/yvTSwNzhbczXm3YMQtV@4Ra2@Y3Tm/4bUEv3RIbUth6sjzqvsFz2VH2Mb9yi3@5y7Xvw)

Comment: hey! +1 from me then!

Comment: @Jenny_mathy it's better now once I switch to C

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica

```
(t=0;
 f=PrimePi[#];
 d=#2;
 For[i=1,i<=f,i++,If[PrimitiveRoot[Prime[i],d]==d,t++]]; 
 N[t/f])&[1000000,2]//AbsoluteTiming
```

[Try it online](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/)  Paste the code and press shift-enter

Takes 3.2 sec to find 1.000.000

Comment: This should have `PrimitiveRoot[Prime[i],d]==d` to work in full generality. Otherwise, given input b=3, it will not count a prime that has 3 as a primitive root if it also has 2 as a primitive root, because it will find 2 first.

Comment: @MishaLavrov if you see the edit history you'll see that this was my first approach but then I thought it wasn't necessary. I'll change it back. thanks!

Comment: @Jenny_mathy hey we're on the same order of magnitude :P

Comment: I believe that `NextPrime` might be a bit faster than `Prime`.

Answer (score 2):

## C++11 + [libop](https://github.com/orlp/libop)

1.23 sec on my slow laptop for 10,000,000.

```c
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#include "libop/op.h"


// Returns 2^-32 mod m, -m^(-1) mod 2^32
inline std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> mont_modinv32(uint64_t m) {
    uint64_t a = 1ull << 31;
    uint64_t u = 1;
    uint64_t v = 0;

    while (a > 0) {
        a = a >> 1;
        if ((u & 1) == 0) {
            u = u >> 1; v = v >> 1;
        } else {
            u = ((u ^ m) >> 1) + (u & m);
            v = (v >> 1) + (1ull << 31);
        }
    }

    return std::make_pair(u, v);
}

// Returns (ab)R mod n given aR mod n, bR mod n, n and -n^(-1) mod R, with R = 2^32
inline uint64_t montmul32(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t n, uint64_t nneginv) {
    uint64_t T = a*b;
    uint32_t m = T*nneginv; // m = T*-n^(-1) (mod 2^32)
    uint64_t t = (T + m*n) >> 32;
    return t >= n ? t - n : t;
}


double f(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    std::vector<uint32_t> primes;
    op::primes_below(a + 1, std::back_inserter(primes));


    int num_primitives = 0;

    for (auto p : primes) {
        if (p == 2) {
            num_primitives += b == 1;
            continue;
        }

        uint32_t s = p - 1;
        uint32_t pneginv = mont_modinv32(p).second;
        uint32_t montb = (uint64_t(b) << 32) % p;
        uint64_t mont1 = (1ull << 32) % p;

        uint32_t pows[32] = {montb};
        for (int i = 1; s >> i; ++i) {
            montb = montmul32(montb, montb, p, pneginv);
            pows[i] = montb;
        }

        bool primitive_root = true;
        for (auto& kv : op::factorization(s)) {
            uint32_t e = s / kv.first;

            uint64_t r = mont1;
            for (int i = 0; e; ++i) {
                if (e & 1) r = montmul32(r, pows[i], p, pneginv);
                e >>= 1;
            }

            if (r == mont1) {
                primitive_root = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        num_primitives += primitive_root;
    }

    return num_primitives / double(primes.size());
}
```